# How to get control values and modify them in Page Methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, pagemethods

I have couple of controls in the page. I need to modify these value in Page method. How can I do that?. When I modify those values in page method should reflect in page?

Please give me expample.

Comment: What do you mean by "page methods"? Are your controls .NET controls or HTML?

Comment: By page methods, do you mean the PageMethods option of web service integration with AJAX, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<!-- or ToolkitScriptManager, but remember to put only one -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function invokeMethod() {
        x = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
        PageMethods.theMethod(x, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
    }
    function OnSuccess(r) {
        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = r;
    }
    function OnFailure(r) {
        alert(r._message);
    }
</script>
```

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static string theMethod(string x)
    {
        return x + "!!!";
    }
```