# Embeding web service method to the .ascx(user control)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-controls, webmethod

It didn't work and i think it won't but i wanted to ask you(last chance).

I have a simple ascx file. It has one select element which retrieves sub categories when it is selected (over web service).
I want to write my web method in ascx.cs file instead of to write in other asmx file.

ASCX.CS file

```
protected void public Page_Load(....){
   //(because i can't give the ascx file path :)
    TheAspxFileWhichContainsMyUserControl = Request.Url.LocalPath
}

[WebMethod]
static public string f_GetSubCats(int _iCatId){
    return "<select><option value=1>One</option></select>";
}
```

ASCX file:

```
<script type="...">
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%=TheAspxFileWhichContainsMyUserControl%>/f_GetSubCats",
        data:...
        ...........
        success: function(msg){
            // append new select to the container
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's not going to work. You need to create a proper ASMX web service, so IIS can process it accordingly. (a ASPX page cannot handle a web service request - there is no proxy created). Also - you need to decorate your WebMethod with `[ScriptService]` so it can be called by AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863898/how-to-get-control-values-and-modify-them-in-page-methods/3864343#3864343)